# AirPush android: not working on tablets

Tags: android, airpush

I have been trying to integrate AirPush into my application(banner ads). It works well on phones, but when I launch my app on tablets, AirPush returns: "Ad json:

```
{"status":204,"message":"ADS Not Available"}".
```

That's how I"m creating the ad banner:

```
private static final int AD_DELAY = 45;
adView=new AdView(activity, AdView.BANNER_TYPE_IN_APP_AD, AdView.PLACEMENT_TYPE_INTERSTITIAL, AD_DELAY, false, false, 
             AdView.ANIMATION_TYPE_LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
```

Has anybody faced the trouble? Thanks in advance for response

Comment: There must be no active ads campaigns for your region at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I did nothing, but when I came back to the tablet a few hours later the ads appeared.